# Javascript AJAX file download

Tags: ajax, binary

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
$.post( '/generate/file', json_data_striginfied, function( data ) {
    var win = window.open()
    window.write(data)
});
```

where data returned is binary data (a PDF file)?

I've tried it and the new window contains the binary data as text, it doesn't force a download. I would like it to force a download of the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the remote PDF url to the new window source url.